# HTTP 429 from Microsoft Graph API requests

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-429

We have a third-party Azure AD application which uses the Microsoft Graph API. This application has not been changed in Production for around 2 months, and we have not had any issues so far.

Since this morning, I am unable to login to the application due to `HTTP 429` responses on requests to the Office 365 Graph API. This is happening to requests on both `/messages` and `/people` endpoints. See below screenshot of developer console:

[image: devconsole]

Would someone be able to advise if there have been any recent changes to the throttling limits on the Graph API?

I don't understand why this would suddenly start happening when there have been no production changes to our application for months.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on throttling at [Microsoft Graph throttling guidance](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/throttling). Without knowing how your application is authenticating or how often the endpoints are called it is difficult to asses exactly what is happening here.

More concerning here is the use of the `/beta` endpoint in production. Using the `/beta` endpoint in a production environment is almost certain to lead to your app unexpectedly failing. While every effort is made to ensure changes to the `/v1.0` endpoint are non-breaking, this is *not* the case for `/beta`. Breaking changes in that endpoint are to be expected.

> Note: The APIs in the beta endpoint are subject to change. We don't recommend that you use them in your production apps.